# What performance problems do Datomic partitions solve?

Tags: performance, partitioning, datomic

I'm trying to plan the partitions for my Datomic schema, but I'm not sure what problems will be solved by partitions and what other won't.

How can things go wrong when you partition incorrectly?

Is it about network roundtrips? Reducing Peer memory footprint? In-memory query performance?

In particular, which of the following approaches are not valid?

- "I have a lot of 'website user' entities, but most of their bytes weight is in their hashed password and salt. So I'll put those attributes in a different entity in another partition so it does not fill up my Peers when doing aggregation jobs."
- "I have a few hundreds entities that will be involved in almost every query, so I'll make a partition just for those to make sure they're always in the object cache".
- "The entities I query together tend to be created at the same time, so I'll have several partitions that contain the same kind of entities, but I'll change the one in which I save new entities every 3 months."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EAVT` index contains datoms sorted by entity id. The partition is encoded in the high-bits of those ids. Because of that partitions are used to improve peer caching by offering you a way to control data locality.

If you know that a query often involves a common set of attributes, you should place all those attribute in the same partition so that the segments that are brought from storage contain as many useful datoms as possible.

To answer your question, choosing partitions effectively will improve query performance by leveraging peer caching i.e. avoiding additional network round-trips to storage.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also comment on the 3 approches listed at the end of the question?

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck #1 and #2 are valid. I don't think #3 is generally valid because entity ids are currently monotonically increasing numbers so if you're only creating entities there's no need to create partitions because they will naturally end up close together i.e. #3 may be valid now. However, that depends on the internals of those entity ids and so it's harder to rely on.